# Wscript.shell.run and Wscript.shell.exec do not display the same outputs

Tags: javascript, windows, ftp, cmd, wsh

I use an ActiveXObject in Javascript.

`var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`

`exec = shell.exec('cmd /c ftp -i -A -s:file.ftp host);`

`var output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll();`

I'm getting the **expected** error "Could not create file" because the file already exists on the server. Everything's ok here. But the output doesn't display the **error codes** of **ftp**, while the Run method does (553 Could not create file).

I do not use Run method because the only output possible consists in redirecting the output into a file, on the client machine.

Trust me, I read a lot of websites (including Windows official descriptions of Run, Exec)

How can I get the error codes of ftp command using WScript.Shell.Exec command?

More info:

exec.StdOut.ReadAll() output ->

```
"bin
cd my_dir/
mput file_path file_path
Could not create file.
Could not create file.
quit"
```

output file from WScript.shell.run ->

```
ftp> bin
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> cd my_dir/
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> mput file_path file_path
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
553 Could not create file.
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
553 Could not create file.
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: [`WshScriptExec.stdErr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye284tb8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)  couldn't solve the problem?

Comment: I used `exec.StdErr.ReadAll()` and, sadly, this doesn't work as expected. This displays the "login successful" message before the ftp prompt appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution on a 8 years old post. (http://computer-programming-forum.com/61-wsh/813f07658378176c.htm)

In order to get the complete output from ftp command using Exec method, the -v option has to be added to ftp command.
Works like a charm.

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
exec = shell.exec(cmd /c ftp -i -v -A -s:file.ftp host);
var output = exec.StdOut.ReadAll();
```